# MongoDB query update nested list of objects

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a users table in MongoDB where the format looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ID"),
    "user" : {
                 "id" : "userId",
                 "info" : "user info",
                 "subscriptions" : [
                        {
                            "subName" : "sub1",
                            "frequency" : 1,
                            "contentId" : "contentId"
                        }
                 ]
             }
}
```

I would like to add a subscription object to that array named "subscriptions." Here is what my code currently looks like and it doesn't work. My JSONParser in this case does work and returns the correct array.

```
QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilder.start("user.id").is("userId");
DBCursor cursor = mongoClient.find(builder.get())

while (cursor.hasNext()){
    DBObject user = cursor.next();
    BasicDBList subscriptions = (BasicDBList)JSONParser.parseObject(user, "user.subscriptions");

    subscriptions.add(subscriptionDBObject);

    DBObject updateSubs = new BasicDBObject();
    updateSubs.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("subscriptions" : subscriptions);

    mongoClient.update(user, updateSubs);
}
```

This runs but the user is never edited and the WriteResult returns "updatedExisting" : false. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me what I have done wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Java driver, so I won't suggest any code, but I believe you are looking for mongo's [Array Update Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/). I think the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) or [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator will serve your needs.

Mongo's example for using $push:

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $push: { scores: 89 } }
)
```

Be sure you understand the performance implications of using growing embedded arrays in mongodb. See here: [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays)

You might also find this post helpful: [Thinking About Arrays In Mongodb](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/)